# Minimap Render texture Mouse Hover Detect on 3d Object in world space

Tags: unity, c#, minimap

I have a **resizeable minimap** which is based on **render texture**. A camera rendering 3d space on Render Texture and then I used the texture as minimap. Now, I have a specific requirement to identify mouse hover on an object in Minimap(render texture). It may sound silly but I have to show some object information on minimap on mouse hover like a tooltip.

In **3d space or world space**, I have several objects and they are showing on minimap. Now if any user mouse-hover on the same object on minimap then I want to show tooltip. Is this possible to get 3d space information from render texture?

Answer (score 1):

Your minimap is just another buffer you render to. Same as the screenbuffer, it holds no information other than the pixel rgba values.

What you need is a translation between minimap coordinates to worldspace coordinates. So that e.g. the, say, 400x400 px the minimap takes up on your monitor, map to the 1000x1000 area of worldspace you display on that minimap.

So with the above values we select minimap-pixel 200/100, we get world-space 500/250.

Comment: More explaniation required? and how do i get aea is rending by minimap

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan what do you need explained more? The world-space displayed by your minimap will be whatever is in your camera's limits. I have no idea where on your screen your minimap is, so I can't tell you whaat to test against...

Comment: i have updated my question with the picture maybe it will helpful.

Comment: I don't see the picture. Can you verify that your question is formatted the way you intend?